# How do I cultivate an amazingly large collection of listening music?

Tags: audio-software, spotify, playlists

It is very difficult for me to listen to music, because I have a tendency to find a song that I like a lot and hit replay again and again. And I can get quite stubborn about refusing to expose my ears to new artists. It results in less exploration and consequently lost time in experiencing the full diversity of American music.

For a research project, it is necessary for me to cultivate an amazingly large music library sampling all popular American songs since the Woodstock music festival (August 15–18, 1969) until the emergence of COVID-19 (December of 2019). This is not a school assignment.

What would be the easiest step-by-step approach to accomplish this goal?

My choice of implement is Spotify.

PS: There will be a natural stopping point, so it will certainly not be necessary for me to actually exhaust all the music. The natural stopping point is when a list I'm feeding the song lyrics to stops growing. The list is a wordcount of basic words. It will stop growing when all the common words in the song lyrics are repeated, and so feeding more song lyrics just results in itself (idempotency).

Comment: @njuffa Because a human mind still needs to process the information.

Comment: Start by exploring artists that you like, check out their albums that you haven't heard before. Running short of those, look for similar artists or artists in the same genre. Also I'm not sure why you'd restrict yourself to American artists? There are some genres where American artists dominates/dominated and other genres where there aren't many American artists at all. For example no matter your genre of preference, it is hard to ignore the UK, for the time period you give.

Comment: @Amarth Thank you for the information. I did not know that some genres are sparsely populated by Americans but dominated by the English. What would be examples of some of these genres?

Comment: Heavy metal, punk, britpop, eurodance/techno (and naturally gaelic/British folk music)... I'm sure there are lots of other examples. While USA has been dominant in Jazz, Blues, Funk, Soul, Country, Hip Hop etc.

Comment: @Fomalhaut The UK is not just England.

Comment: @DaveP Forgive my American ignorance 

Comment: "Cultivate" how? Do you only need access to the lyrics, or to the songs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try AI recommendation platforms like [Pandora](https://www.pandora.com/). The more you listen, the more it will understand your taste, and recommend other similar music

Comment: Thank you. Pandora might be greater than Spotify.

Answer (score 1):

I have a collection like the one you seek, but I amassed it gradually, over the course of decades. I shudder to think how much money it represents in total. It would probably take me months to listen through it all, beginning to end.

If you're just looking for lyrics, why not just hit up a lyrics site like "Genius," You might be able to program a spider bot (or train an AI spider) to do it for you.

If you're actually trying to expand your musical horizons, one place to start might be a top songs list, like the ones *Rolling Stone* puts out, or "top hits of the last 50 years" videos on YouTube. Those are biased and limited selections, of course, but it gives you a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

(online) radio stations. While listening to HardRadio.com, I've created a playlist with some 500 tracks, with some 200 more pending to be added, and greatly increased the scope of styles that I like.